# Have days display with commas except for the last one

Tags: php, html

I have the following if statements that gather up all the days that were selected before it becomes displayed.

```
$daysUsed = "";

if($this->dayweeksunsession==1){
    $daysUsed .= "Su ";
}

if($this->dayweekmonsession==1){
    $daysUsed .=  "M ";
}

if($this->dayweektuessession==1){
    $daysUsed .=  "T ";
}

if($this->dayweekwedsession==1){
    $daysUsed .=  "W ";
}

if($this->dayweekthurssession==1){
    $daysUsed .=  "Th ";
}

if($this->dayweekfrisession==1){
    $daysUsed .=  "F ";
}

if($this->dayweeksatsession==1){
    $daysUsed .=  "Sa ";
}

if($daysUsed !=="") {
    echo "</span><br/>Days of the Week: <span class='BoxReviewOutput'>";
    echo $daysUsed;
}
```

My question here is how can I make this so that commas will be displayed for each day of the week that was chosen in the session except for the last one.

For example: Sunday and Tuesday were chosen.  So it would be displayed "Su, T"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your ifs add a commma:

```
$daysUsed = "Whatever, ";
```

Then before you output the final string:

`$daysUsed = substr($daysUsed, 0, -2);`

**EDIT:** -1 needs to be -2, to account for the spacing between days.

Comment: In your example it would nee to be `-2` as you have a space in the string too.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: I realized that, and updated it just before you commented :)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. the substr worked! Will accept answer in 6 minutes.

Comment: @Josh thanks - it was a -2 when I changed it on my end. :) Thank you for updating your answer

Answer (score 7):

Use [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$days = array("Su", "M", ....., "Sa");
echo implode(",", $days);
```

Answer (score 1):

i'd use an array and implode it but in your case i'd need to use this

```
echo substr($daysUsed,0,-1)
```

in this case I remove the last character from the string

Answer (score 0):

$daysUsed = trim( $daysUsed, "," );

trim() is by far the better option - minimal function, does what you want for your intended purpose.